# In + ~ing vs In + noun?

Tags: phrase-choice

My textbook says, *In rotating, the pulverisers break up the coal into fragments.*

Can you use *In the rotation* instead of *In rotating*? Are they the same?

Answer (score 0):

No.

> **By rotating**, the pulverisers break up the coal into fragments.

I presume *rotating* here refers to some rotating mechanism.

But *in the rotation* refers to a cycling of items, for example:

> He was **in the rotation** to play first base on the team.

meaning several players took turns playing first base.

But that doesn't work in your example.

Comment: Indeed, I agree with you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No they are not equivalent.  However, a sentence using "rotation" can be written to have a similar meaning.

> - In rotating, the pulverisers break up the coal into fragments.
> - By their rotation, the pulverisers break up the coal into fragments.
> - The rotation of the pulverisers breaks up the coal into fragments.

All these have much the same meaning, and all are grammatical.

The word "rotation"  can refer to a situation in which people or things take turns. But it can also refer to a circular or rotary movement. But in this form it must normally be made clear what is rotating.

One can say "the rotation of the earth" meaning its daily turn about its axis. One can say "The rotation of the wheels as they move along the road", again each wheel turns on its axis, or more concretely its axle.

Comment: I see. Sorry for the belated response. I wondered if "rotating" without its object is acceptable, but it is OK. Thank you.